# Deciding on a primary key according to value size in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, primary-key, identity

I want to ask a question to optimize SQL Server performance. Assume I have an entity - say `Item` - and I must assign a primary key for it. It has columns and two of them are expected to be unique, one of them is expected to be bigger than the other as tens of characters.

How should I decide primary key?

Should one of them be PK, if so which one, or both, or should I create an Identity number as PK? This is important for me because the entity "Item" would have relations with some other entities and I think the complexity of PK would affect the performance of SQL Server queries.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would go with an `IDENTITY` Primary Key with unique constraints on both the mentioned unique keys and indexes for additonal lookups.

You have to remember that by default SQL Server creates the primary key as the clustered index, which impacts how it is stored on disc. If the new `ITEMS` came in at random, variance there could be a lot of fragmentation on either the primary keys.

Also, unless cascades and foreign keys are switched on, you would have to manually maintain the relational integrety of the data (unless you use `IDENTITY`)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the **primary key** is really only used to **uniquely identify** each row - so the only requirements for it are: it **has to be unique** and typically also should not contain `NULL`.

Anything else is most likely more relevant for the **clustering key** in SQL Server - the column (or set of columns) by which the data is physically ordered on disk. By default, the primary key is also the clustering key in SQL Server.

The clustering key is the most important choice in SQL Server because it has far reaching performance implications. A **good** clustering key is

- narrow
- unique
- stable
- if possible ever-increasing

It has to be unique so that it can be added to each and every single nonclustered index for lookup into the actual data tables - if you pick a non-unique column (or set of columns), SQL Server will add a 4-byte "uniquefier" for you.

It should be as narrow as possible, since it's stored in a lot of places. Try to stick to 4 bytes for an `INT` or 8 bytes for a `BIGINT` - avoid long and variable length `VARCHAR` columns since those are both too wide, and the variable length also carries additional overhead. Because of this, sets of columns are also rather rarely a good choice.

The clustering key should be **stable** - value shouldn't change over time - since every time a value changes, potentially a lot of index entries (in the clustered index itself, and every single nonclustered index, too) need to be updated which causes a lot of unnecessary overhead.

And if it's ever-increasing (like an `INT IDENTITY`), you also can avoid most **page splits** - an extremely expensive and involved procedure that happens if you use random values (like GUID's) as your clustering key.

So in brief: an `INT IDENTITY` is ideal - GUIDs, variable length strings, or combinations of columns are typically less of a good choice.

Comment: I wont retrigger the age old argument, just point you to it. http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/ - you can pretty much gurantee the SO db has guids, and its a big db.

Comment: @jenson-button-event: in that case, you **must** read Kim Tripp's [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and clustering keys](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/) - and I'm *pretty sure* the SO database does ***not*** have GUIDs as its PK .....

Comment: @jenson-button-event: if you go compose your own online query against the SO database at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new - you will see they're using ***INT*** as their primary key - as any sane (SQL Server) DB developer will !

Comment: you are making an argument about clustered indexes, not primary keys

Comment: As I understand, it is a controversial issue to use `INT IDENTITY` or longer unique data such as `GUID` as PK. However it sounds me more reasonable to use identity thank to its lower size, efficient usage as clustering key and common usage.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the one you will use to identify the records in queries and joins to other tables. Size is relative, and whilst a consideration usually not an issue since the PK will be indexed and the other unique column can make use also of a unique index.

The `uniqueidentifier` data type for e.g. is a 36 character long string representation and performs fine as a primary key under the majority of circumstances.

Comment: But all indexes point at the primary key. So if your PK is 64 bytes, every leaf of every index is 64 bytes.

Comment: Infrastructure should not be a constraint on software design. This is why I have a number of DBAs hidden away in the walls of my house.

Comment: Check out [Disk space is cheap .... - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/) by Kimberly Tripp. Disk space is **not** the most important point - **excessive fragmentation** and thus excessive page splits with GUID-based clustered indexes and generally worse performance are much more of an issue

Comment: I don't mean to be inflammatory but in the real world, infrastructure _is_ a constraint; and database design is not software design. In the real world, enterprises may or may not have DBA's that can solve issues introduced by a database design approach where every PK is a uniqueidentifer (rather than a small meaningful key) Some forethought and understanding beforehand stops these things happening. I'm sure you've cracked open some code and though 'this is wrong and now it's so deeply embedded I can't fix it". It happens to me every day!